# How do I list the database files contained in a SQL Server 2005 backup file using T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, restore

How do I list the database files contained in a SQL Server 2005 backup file using T-SQL?

For instance:

The restore process will create:

```
bob.mdf
bob.ldf
```

etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`RESTORE FILELISTONLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173778%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: This is why gbn is one of my favourites here.  Short accurate answers, right to the point.